# Modsecurity create config file with rules for specific URL

Tags: apache, security, mod-security

I'm starting to learn about `ModSecurity` and rule creation so say I know a page in an web app is vulnerable to cross site scripting. For argument's sake lets say page /blah.html is prone to XSS.

Would the rule in question look something like this?:

```
SecRule ARGS|REQUEST_URI "blah" REQUEST_HEADERS “@rx <script>” id:101,msg: ‘XSS Attack’,severity:ERROR,deny,status:404
```

Is it possible to create a config file for that particular page (or even wise to do so?) or better said is it possible to create rules for particular URL's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite right as a few things wrong with this rule as it's written now. But think you get the general concept.

To explain what's wrong with the rule as it currently stands takes a fair bit of explanation:

First up, ModSecurity syntax for defining rules is made up of several parts:

1. SecRule
2. field or fields to check
3. values to check those fields for
4. actions to take

You have two sets of parts 2 & 3 which is not valid. If you want to check 2 things you need to chain two rules together, which I'll show an example of later.

Next up you are checking the Request Headers for the script tag. This is not where most XSS attacks exist and you should be checking the arguments instead - though see below for further discussion on XSS.

Also checking for `<script>` is not very thorough. It would easily be defeated by `<script type="text/javascript">` for example. Or `<SCRIPT>` (should add a `t:lowercase` to ignore case). Or by escaping characters that might be processed by your parts of your application.

Moving on, there is no need to specify the `@rx` operator as that's implied if no other operator is given. While no harm in being explicitly it's a bit odd you didn't give it for `blah` but did for the `<script>` bit.

It's also advisable to specify a phase rather than use default (usually phase 2). In this case you'd want phase 2 which is when all Request Headers and Request Body pieces are available for processing, so default is probably correct but best to be explicit.

And finally 404 is "page not found" response code. A 500 or 503 might be a better response here.

So your rule would be better rewritten as:

```
SecRule REQUEST_URI "/blah.html" id:101,phase:2,msg: ‘XSS Attack’,severity:ERROR,deny,status:500,chain
   SecRule ARGS "<script" "t:lowercase"
```

Though this still doesn't address all the ways that the basic check you are doing for a script tag can be worked around, as mentioned above. The [OWASP Core Rule Set](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project) is a free ModSecurity set of rules that has been built up over time and has some XSS rules in it that you can check out. Though be warned some of their regexprs get quite complex to follow!

ModSecurity also works better as a more generic check, so it's unusual to want to protect just one page like this (though not completely unheard of). If you know one page is vulnerable to a particular attack then it's often better to code that page, or how it's processed, to fix the vulnerability, rather than using ModSecurity to handle it. Fix the problem at source rather than patching round it, is always a good mantra to follow where possible. You would do that by sanitising and escaping input HTML code from inputs for example.

Saying that it is often a good short term solution to use a ModSecurity rule to get a quick fix in while you work on the more correct longer term fix - this is called "virtual patching". Though sometimes they have a tendency to become the long term solutions then as no one gets time to fix the core problem.

If however you wanted a more generic check for "script" in **any** arguments for **any** page, then that's what ModSecurity is more often used for. This helps add extra protection on what already should be there in a properly coded app, as a back up and extra line of defence. For example in case someone forgets to protect one page out of many by sanitising user inputs.

So it might be best dropping the first part of this rule and just having the following to check all pages:

```
SecRule ARGS "<script" id:101,phase:2,msg: ‘XSS Attack’,severity:ERROR,deny,status:500,"t:lowercase"
```

Finally [XSS is quite a complex subject](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Types_of_Cross-Site_Scripting). Here I've assumed you want to check parameters sent when requesting a page. So if it uses user input to construct the page and displays the input, then you want to protect that - known as "reflective XSS." There are other XSS vulnerabilities though. For example:

- If bad data is stored in a database and used to construct a page. Known as "stored XSS". To address this you might want to check the results returned from the page in the RESPONSE_BODY parameter in phase 4, rather than the inputs sent to the page in the ARGS parameter in phase 2. Though processing response pages is typically slower and more resource intensive compared to requests which are usually much smaller.
- You might be able to execute a XSS without going through your server e.g. If loading external content like a third party commenting system. Or page is served over http and manipulated between server and cling. This is known as "DOM-based XSS" and as ModSecurity is on your server then it cannot protect against these types of XSS attacks.

Gone into quite a lot of detail there but hope that helps explain a little more. I found the [ModSecurity Handbook](https://www.feistyduck.com/books/modsecurity-handbook/) the best resource for teaching yourself ModSecurity despite its age.